# Find nearest point between Point and list of LineStrings without for-loop

Tags: python, shapely

Assume a list of Linestrings and a single point

```
line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 1)])
line2 = LineString([(0, 1), (1, 0)])
line3 = LineString([(1, 0), (1, 1)])

line_list = [line1, line2, line3]

point = Point([2, 2])
```

I am looking for an approach to calculate the nearest points between the different lines and the single point. I know the shapely.ops.nearest_points function but as far as I understand the function, it can only process two geometries and I would have to iterate through all lines and process each individually. If my line_list consists of several hundred or thousand of LineStrings, this approach would be quite inefficient. Therefore, I am looking for a function which allows efficient calculation of the nearest_points:

```
def get_nearest_points(point, line_list):
   ... do magic ...
   return nearest_points
```

In our case, the return value is a list of nearest_points. One for each line in the line_list.

```
[(<POINT (2 2)>, <POINT (1 1)>), (<POINT (2 2)>, <POINT (0.5 0.5)>), (<POINT (2 2)>, <POINT (1 1)>)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```
from shapely import line_interpolate_point, line_locate_point
dist = line_locate_point(line_list, point)
line_interpolate_point(line_list, dist).tolist()
```

gives the result :

```
<POINT (1 1)>, <POINT (0.5 0.5)>, <POINT (1 1)>]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works just fine. I used your approach with more than 96.000 lines and 1 point, and it took around 0.27 seconds. In comparison, the approach with nearest_points took around 1.6 seconds